# How can I float a "shape-outside" div to the left of text positioned at the bottom of the parent container?

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty sure this is impossible (at least with just HTML and CSS) since I've been searching everywhere and trying everything to no avail... this question is my last hope.

Basically, I have a diagonal line across from bottom to top of container (using "shape-outside" css property) which floats to the right of the upper text. What I want is to have a copy of this diagonal line which floats to the left of the lower text, but the problem is that by positioning the lower text, I take it out of the flow, meaning I can't wrap it using float now. Is there some trick to getting this desired effect?

[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5Td6.png)

[Notice here how when I resize, the text wraps along the diagonal up top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxiNb.png)

I want the same thing for the bottom text, rather than getting cut off.

Some other details:

- I am using clip-path to get the desired shape of the left and right side
- Both the left and right sides are divs, each 100% wide and high. I use a negative margin to get them to overlap
- within the left side div, I have my "slant" div which uses shape-outside to make a diagonal line, and the text elements which wrap around the slant which floats right.
- within the right side div, I am using absolute positioning on a container of the text, to position it 0px from the bottom of the parent div, but this is problematic since now it cannot wrap around a floated element (the diagonal in my case)

Hopefully someone has a trick for this!

**Edit: code**

Note: I am using riotjs for custom tags, but I have not yet added anything to them

```
<left>
    <div id="slant"></div>
    <bean id="fighter">
        <name>{props.fighter.name}</name>
        <bio factoids={props.fighter.factoids}></bio>
    </bean>
</left>

<right>

    <div>
        <div id="slant"></div>
        <bean id="challenger">
            <bio factoids={props.challenger.factoids}></bio>
            <name>{props.challenger.name}</name>
        </bean>
    </div>
</right>

<style>

    left {
        display: block;
        background-color: pink;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 0, 20% 100%, 0 100%);
        margin-bottom: -100vh;
    }

    right {
        display: block;
        background-color: lightblue;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        clip-path: polygon(80% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 20% 100%);
    }

    right > div {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    right > div > bean {
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
    }

    left #slant {
        shape-outside: polygon(80% 0, 20% 100%);
        float: right;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    h3, ul {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: can you post the code of what you have as well ?

Comment: Add padding so it cuts the padding and not the text

Comment: added code, a bit wonky right now since I am using riotjs for custom tags, but the structure should be the same were they divs with ids or such.

Comment: @Stanley I want the text to actually wrap on the right of the "shape-outside" slant, while also being positioned at the bottom of the containing div

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking wrong by making each color shape a section. You need two sections where each one will have two colors.

I also added a small JS to push the content to the bottom using margin because we cannot rely on `position:absolute`

```js
var setMargin = function() {
  var h1 = document.querySelector('.second').offsetHeight;
  var h2 = document.querySelector('.second div').offsetHeight;
  document.querySelector('.second div').style.marginTop= (h1 - h2)+'px';

}
setMargin();
window.onresize = setMargin;
```

```css
.first,
.second{
  height:50vh;
  min-height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
.first {
 background:pink;
}
.second {
 background:lightblue;
}
.first:before {
  content:"";
  float:right;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  background:lightblue;
  shape-outside:polygon(40% 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%);
  clip-path:polygon(40% 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%);
}
.second:before {
  content:"";
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  background:pink;
  shape-outside:polygon(0 0,100% 0,60% 100%,0 100%);
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,60% 100%,0 100%);
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam consectetur gravida lectus at dignissim. Aenean quis augue a mi volutpat molestie ac ut justo. Phasellus ac libero a 
</div>
<div class="second">
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam consectetur gravida lectus at dignissim. Aenean quis augue a mi volutpat molestie ac ut justo. Phasellus ac libero a magna aliquam fringilla sed in nibh. </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Holy balls you have no idea how much i appreciate your answer. One eensy weensy caveat though, I need it to be responsive to the page's width/heights being swapped (like rotating a phone). I think I should be able to figure this out expanding on your idea.

Comment: @bean it should be responsive everywhere. You simply need to add another JS code to listen to the "orientation change" and you apply the code

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided to go with another solution, which I'm leaving here if anyone runs into the same problem.

It's most definitely one helluva hack, but it works well.

I ended up just reflecting the right side vertically, and then reflecting each line of text vertically as well.